# Most efficient way to blink a light

Tags: java, swing

I have a simple Component that I want to blink everytime my application receives a "message". Currently I am creating a new thread to 'light' the Component, sleep, then reset the Component. How could I accomplish this in a better way? I know that threads are expensive.

```
public class StatusLights extends JComponent {

private static final Color unlit = Color.lightGray;

private HashMap<String, Color> colors = new HashMap<String, Color>();

public StatusLights() {
    // start with no colors

    colors.put("TOP", unlit);
    colors.put("MIDDLE", unlit);
    colors.put("BOTTOM", unlit);
}

// 1 = top 2 = mid 3 = bottom
public void light(Color color, int pos) {
    switch (pos) {
    case (1): {
        colors.put("TOP", color);
        break;
    }
    case (2): {
        colors.put("MIDDLE", color);
        break;
    }
    case (3): {
        colors.put("BOTTOM", color);
        break;
    }
    default: {
        // not valid position

    }
    }
    repaint();

}

public void clear() {
    colors.put("TOP", unlit);
    colors.put("MIDDLE", unlit);
    colors.put("BOTTOM", unlit);

    repaint();
}

public void blink(final Color color, final int i) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            light(color, i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            clear();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

Comment: Suggestion: make final `int`s `private final int TOP = 1`, `private final int MIDDLE = 2`, etc. Then `colors.put(TOP, unlit)`, and `colors.put(pos, color)` will work, no switch needed. Alternatively, make it an enum so you can typecheck when you pass in your parameters.

Comment: @MirroredFate would it be even better to use a byte? Since this value will only ever be 1, 2, or 3. Or would the difference be negligible?

Comment: Probably not. If you are super worried about memory and trying to store your data as compactly as possible then you would probably store int in some config byte of data as flags- i.e, you would have a byte whose value was maybe `0110-0000`, where the first three bits would indicate top, bottom, and middle, and if they were `0` they would be off and `1` would be on.

But you're working in Java, so you probably have memory available. I would go with the enum idea as that gives you more explicit control over what's going where.

Comment: [An example of what I'm talking about](http://ideone.com/70vrHs)

Answer (score 1):

Use a Swing `javax.swing.Timer`, it's repeatable at a regular time interval, provides a level of thread isolation/synchronisation (as it timer event is enqueued in the event queue and execute within the context Event Dispatching Thread one at a time) and prevents any possibility of violating Swings single thread rules.

An alternative is to use a `SwingWorker` and make use of its `publish`/`process` methods...